# Is there any classical correspondence of the Jacobi identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets

In QM, the commutator were closely related to the poison bracket, so much so that to promote the classical operators to the quantum operators were often associated as

\begin{equation}
\{A,B\} \text{(classical)} \Leftrightarrow [A,B] \text{(quantum)}
\end{equation}

However, the Lie algebra which often used in the QM satisfied

\begin{equation}
[X,[Y,Z]]+[Y,[Z,X]]+[Z,[X,Y]]=0
\end{equation}

But there was rarely the discussion of the classical correspondence of the Jacobi identity.

If the classical correspondence of the Jacobi identity exists, what could it tell about the algebra of the generators, what kind of the conservation was it associated?

If it did not exist, could the Jacobi identity be viewed as some sort of quantum mechanical property that's part of the quantum conventions?

Is there any classical correspondence of the Jacobi identity?

(*Very much off the topic but what's the implication to the developing theories such as the string theory. Is it possible to "string-lize" the Jacobi identity to some sort of "string bracket"?)

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: The Jacobi identity is one of the properties of the Poisson bracket, [as mentioned in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket#Properties). I don't really understand the question "what kind of the conservation was it associated?"

Comment: Hi ShoutOutAndCalculate. To reopen this post (v2) consider to focus the post around questions not already answered by the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Yeah... I realized the question was a bit wrong when woke up. In a book readying, the lie algebra with the bracket thought to define a manifold with the group element, where the generator defined the tangent vector. The poison bracket obviously stated something very similar, and the Jacobi identity should vanish on a smooth manifold.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I guess the question only make sense if we start to introduce topological terms to the manifold, where the associativity $x_ix_j x_k$ no longer hold in the non-associative algebra, and maybe generate an anomaly at the level of the jacobi identity. This actually could be acquired in the strings with the defects.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves a bizarre point, the well known space with a non smooth point, was black hole. (That's why the question was wrong I guess.)